# Possible to add a loop while appending to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm appending some information to the DOM, but realized that some of the information I need is nested within an object. When I do the below bit of code, the part within the loop returns as undefined. Is there a way to iterate over and pull out this information so that I can append it to my page:

```
function placeOnPage(allStopsWithRoutes){
  allStopsWithRoutes.forEach(function(stop){

    $('#stops').append("Stop: " + stop.crossStreets + "<br>" +

        // LOOP HERE
        stop.routes.forEach(function(route){
        "Bus Name: " + busName + "<br>" + 
        "Stops Away: " + stopsAway + "<br>" +
        "Destination: " + destination + "<p>"
        });
        // END LOOP

      );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think strings can be concatenated that way. Change your approach to concatenate before hand and store it in a variable. Then append the variable

```
function placeOnPage(allStopsWithRoutes) {
    allStopsWithRoutes.forEach(function(stop) {
        var concatenatedStr = '';
        stop.routes.forEach(function(route) {
            concatenatedStr += ("Bus Name: " + busName + "<br>" +
                "Stops Away: " + stopsAway + "<br>" +
                "Destination: " + destination + "<p>");
        });
        $('#stops').append("Stop: " + stop.crossStreets + "<br>" + concatenatedStr);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I tried running the loop before appending and your idea of storing within variables. Appreciate it.